# Volume of an octagonal dome

Tags: calculus, geometry, volume, solid-geometry

I need a way to find the volume of an octagonal dome. Can someone help me with the formula for that?
Here's an example of the object I am trying to analyze

[image]

Comment: What's an octagonal dome?

Comment: Something like that https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17974596/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede%202015-12-17%20kl.%2002.14.48.png

Comment: Are the meridians circular arcs?

Comment: Yes they are...

Comment: Found your question on Engineering.SE and followed it this way because this is a more appropriate fit.   Think of ways you could subdivide the shape into something you could easier describe using a formula (i.e. your shape could be broken into pie shaped prisms with their slide side determined by the radius from the center of your dome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic [volume by cross-section](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Volume) problem. The general idea goes as follows: We are given a reasonably simple, bounded solid figure $S$ living in $xyz$-space. Note that a specified value of the variable $z$ determines a horizontal plane that intersects the solid for some range of $z$ values, say $z=a$ to $z=b$. If we can find a formula $A(z)$ that tells us the the area $A$ of the cross-section corresponding to $z$, then the desired volume is
$$\int_a^b A(z) \ dz.$$
Let us apply this to find the volume of a dome whose base is a regular $n$ sided polygon of radius $R$, that has $n$ vertical cross-sections that are semi-circles, and such that all its horizontal cross-sections are again regular $n$ sided polygons. Such a figure for $n=6$ looks like so:

[image]

Again, the base is a regular $n$ sided polygon with radius $R$ and all the other horizontal cross-sections are regular $n$ sided polygons with smaller radius. *Radius* in this context, means the distance from the center to one of the vertices. On octagon with radius $x$ is shown in the figure below on the left. Now, can make a crucial observation by looking at this figure from the side and perpendicular to one of the circles, as shown in the figure below on the right. We then see that $x$ is related to the cross-sectional height $z$ by $x^2 = R^2-z^2$.

[image]

Furthermore, a little elementary geometry (or a reference to [this webpage](http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_regular_polygon.htm)) shows that the area of a regular $n$ sided polygon of radius $x$ is
$$A(x) = \frac{1}{2}nx^2\sin(2\pi/n).$$
Thus, as a function of $z$, we get
$$A(z) = \frac{1}{2}n(R^2-z^2)\sin(2\pi/n).$$
Finally, the volume of the solid is
$$V = \frac{1}{2}n\sin(2\pi/n)\int_0^R (R^2-z^2) \ dz = \frac{1}{3}nR^3\sin(2\pi/n).$$
When the base is an octagon and the radius unspecified (as in your problem), we get volume of $4\sqrt{2}R^3/3$.